# How to pass multiple tests names, as one value in "dotnet test --filter" option

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, nunit

I have this part of my feature scenarios

```
@ID-1
@Browser:Edge
@Browser:Chrome
Given
Scenario: 01.01
    Given I have open website in Browser
    When I open form
    Then the element are visible

@ID-2
@Browser:Edge
@Browser:Chrome
Given
Scenario: 01.02
    Given I have open website in Browser
    When I open form
    Then the element are visible
```

And for example I want run only Scenario 01.01, that has `ID-1`, and only using `Browser:Chrome`

I was try to execute it with `dotnet test --filter ID-1 | Browser:Chrome`, but it runs 3 tests instead of one. It launches Scenario: 01.01, because it has `ID-1`, and launches Scenario: 01.01 and Scenario: 01.02, because they have `Browser:Chrome`

Is it even possible just to run only `Scenario: 01.01`, using its `ID` and `Browser type`?
Because I need to run this scenario specific on Chrome browser

Comment: `|` means `OR`, did you mean to use `&` instead?

Comment: I don't know, that we can use `&`
I tried it, and got an error:

`At line:1 char:46
+ dotnet test --filter Category=Browser:Chrome & Category=LMS-VAL-1
+                                              ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed`

Comment: And If I wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks, I got and error: error `MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.`

Comment: Found a solution
Just need to take all line into double quatation marks `dotnet test --filter "Category=Browser:Chrome & Category=LMS-VAL-1"`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution Just need to take all line into double quatation marks `dotnet test --filter "Category=Browser:Chrome & Category=LMS-VAL-1"`